# What is wrong with this pkcs12 file (pfx)

Tags: openssl

I created a my private CA and form a pkcs12 certificate file for testing. I did this on my Linux box with openssl by:

1. `openssl req -config /etc/openssl.cnf -subj /CN=aa1@2C/O=Ruckus Wireless, Inc./ST=CA/C=US -batch -new -nodes -key users/2C.key -out users/2C.csr`
2. `openssl ca -config /etc/openssl.cnf -extensions client_cert -batch -in users/2C.csr -out users/2C.crt`
3. `openssl pkcs12 -export -out users/2C.pfx -inkey users/2C.key -in users/2C.crt -certfile cacert.pem -passout stdin`

After that, I copied the 2c.pfx to my Windows 7 machine and tried to install it, but the error message bumped out:

> Invalid Public Key Security Object File:
> This file is invalid for use as the following:Personal Information Exchange.

What is the reason for this? Did I create a broken pfx file?

Comment: You can use ASN1 viewer tool (one such tool is http://www.obj-sys.com/asn1-viewer.php). Where, you can look into the schema of the file and check if it conforms to the standard.

Comment: @doptimusprime I was trying to use the tool, unfortunately it is not free, requires registration and validation, do you know about other free tool?

Comment: @DanielV: OpenSSL is free and do not require registration.

Comment: I was looking for a tool to view the *.pfx file, I am facing the same issue described here

Comment: PFX file is PKCS#12 file. So, see the help of `openssl pkcs12`

Comment: https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/display/infra/Extracting+Certificate+and+Private+Key+Files+from+a+.pfx+File

Comment: I had this error with a .crt file. I opened it in Notepad++ and removed the new line at the end. This fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

I also had the message

> Invalid Public Key Security Object File: This file is invalid for use as the following: Personal Information Exchange.

The problem was that the p12-file was on a networkshare which was mapped as a drive.
Copying the file to my real hard drive (C:) solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat obscure (I don't ever recall seeing it, but hey...). First, ensure that you are importing the certificate into the proper store. Most import errors I have encountered are due to he wrong store. I believe you need to install the certificate in the local machine's Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store (Intermediate Certificate Authorities does not work). If that's not a store problem....

Second, try this out from the Microsoft forums. [*Unable to Import Certificate (p12 or pfx File)*](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/50bd9c7c-faaa-46e3-b9a4-a2bb885b180d). (I reproduced it in case Microsoft rearranges their website. But to be clear, its someone else's solution):

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
```

By the way, I think you can check if its well formed according to Microsoft tools with the following. I don't have a Windows machine handy to test it with.

```
certutil -dump 2C.pfx
```

Answer (score 0):

I also received the same error message. In my case it was simply the wrong file extension.