# I get a certificate error on start my node.js server

Tags: node.js

why im getting this error ? and how i can fix this
Node.js version: v14.15.1
certificate: pfx
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxiJW.png)

Error (as seen in image):

```
> node app.js
tls_common. js : 273
       c.context. loadPKCS12(buf) ;
Error : header too long
at Object.createSecureContext (_t1s_common.js:273:19)
at Server.setSecureContext (_t1s_wrap.js:1323:27)
at Server (_t1s_wrap.js:1181:8)
at new Server (https.js:66:14)
```

```
 const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
 const pfx = readFileSync(__dirname + '/src/certs/cert.pfx');
const pid = process.pid

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('/')
  res.send(`${pid}`);
});
const { createServer } = require('https');

 const { createRoutes } = require('./src/routes/index');
 const { createSocket } = require('./src/core/socket');

const https = createServer({
  pfx: pfx,
  passphrase: '',
}, app);

 const io = createSocket(https);
 createRoutes(app, io);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5005; // 8443

https.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`https server started on port:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: 1) Please add the error message as TEXT, not as IMAGE, so you (and others) can find that this question isa duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - crypto.js - PFX header too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392571/node-js-crypto-js-pfx-header-too-long)

Comment: When I double click on the certificate I get an error. 
Invalid Public Key Security Object File
This file is invalid for use as the following: Personal Information Exchange.

Comment: "double click" ??  It does matter if  you do than on a Windows system or on a Linux system (or on another system), and (as for Windows) which application is started when you do "double click".....

Comment: on a Windows system, when you double-click on the certificate opens Certificate Import Wizard, but in my case I get an error that I indicated above

Comment: Did you check: [What is wrong with this pkcs12 file (pfx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429675/what-is-wrong-with-this-pkcs12-file-pfx?rq=1), or any similar links ?

Comment: yes, but I can't find anything that can help me